# How to edit stock availability of product in admin enhanded grid free extension of Magento

Tags: grid, admin, product, magento-1.8, stock

I am able to show Stock Availability column in products grid of Admin Manage products. And I have installed a free extension named Enhanced Admin Grid from this site URL http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html. It is working fine. But I need to edit Stock Availability like the functionality of Status of Admin Enhance Grid. I have had a google search a lot, but there is no solution. If any one knows about this development, please reply me